# How do I solve this problem using 'for' in Python?

Tags: python

```
code_0 = 0,
code_1 = 1,
code_2 = 2

for n in range(3):
    print(code_n)        # <<<<< This is problem



result = 0
         1
         2
```

I want to put a repeating number into a variable.
how I solve?

Comment: better t o save these variable in list

Comment: `code = [0, 1, 2]` then you can access it by in the loop with `code[n]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, You can use `globals()` which returns a dictionary of the variables defined in the environment, and you can call `get()` on this dictionary object to get the value of a variable by its corresponding name.

```py
code_0 = 0
code_1 = 1
code_2 = 2

for n in range(3):
    print(globals().get(f"code_{n}"))

#output:
0
1
2
```

But instead of accessing `globals()` directly, you can define `codes` list with the list of values and get the values in the list by index:

```py
codes = [1,2,3]
for i in range(len(codes)):
    print(codes[i])

#output:
1
2
3
```